# Scrapy : How to write items of different spiders to different MongoDB collections?

Tags: mongodb, scrapy

How to write items of different spider to different MongoDB collections?

The structure of the project is like this:

```
myproject/
    scrapy.cfg
    myproject/
        __init__.py
        items.py
        pipelines.py
        settings.py
        spiders/
            __init__.py
            spider1.py
            spider2.py
            ...
```

According to the docs,https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb

> In this example we’ll write items to MongoDB using pymongo. MongoDB address and database name are specified in Scrapy settings; MongoDB collection is named after item class.

And there is a piece of code from docs:

```
import pymongo

class MongoPipeline(object):

    collection_name = 'scrapy_items'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
        )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert_one(dict(item))
        return item
```

in above code,collection name is:

```
collection_name = 'scrapy_items'
```

**Quesition:**

I want to set different collection names for different spiders,how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert the name you want like below in your crawler class

```
class Spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    collection_name = 'scrapy_items_my_crawler'
```

And change

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
    self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]
```

to

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
    self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]
    if hasattr(spider, 'collection_name'):
       self.collection_name = spider.collection_name
```

This will override the `collection_name` based on your spider, if you spider defines one. If not then it will use the default `scrapy_items`